# libGDX : get Label actor from stage by name

Tags: java, libgdx

My Actor is `Label`. When I get it by name, I don't find `setText(...);` method.

I used :

```
stage.getRoot().findActor("name"). // setText not exist
```

How can I find the `Label` actor ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably need to cast to Label before using:

```
Label labelActor = (Label) stage.getRoot().findActor("name");
labelActor.setText("abc");
```

Comment: ya, that's it. I put the same name between different actors, this was my mistake. your code is good with cast or without it (the same). Anyway, THANX A LOT.